# How to read a .tsf file to a dataframe in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .tsf file.

I want to read it to a dataframe in pandas through a specified path.

How can i do that??

Comment: Can you post upload small sample `.tsf` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you by TSF refer to Tab Separated Fields, then you need to use the `pandas.read_csv('filename.tsf', sep='\t')`

The `sep='\t'` will tell pandas that the fields are separated by tabs.

Comment: Works. Thank you :)